# "order by" feature in main search query language - possible?

Tags: support, feature-request

I can search questions tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) but excluding those tagged with [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), and scored at least +3, like so:

[`[python] score:3 is:question -[pandas]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+score%3A3+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bpandas%5D)

The default ordering here is by "Relevance" which is not useful (I'm not sure what "relevance" even means when there is no text in the search, but it seems to be very similar to an ordering by votes).

Is there a way to also include an ordering in the search language? I want to be able to search for recently posted questions with positive score in some tag. So, something like:

`[python] score:3 is:question -[pandas] orderby:newest`

With expected results like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpython%5d%20score%3a3%20is%3aquestion%20-%5bpandas%5d).

Currently, the only way I could figure to do it is to make the search (by "relevance"), and then clicking on the "tab" for "Newest" - or edit the GET param for the tab into url directly.

Comment: I think I saw someone said you can use a `tab:newest` operator.

Comment: My userscript saves your preferred sort option before you hit the search button or press enter https://stackapps.com/questions/7971/advanced-search-helper-saved-search-bookmarks-and-navigation-improvements

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thanks, I like your scripts and have several of them installed already. If stackoverflow (the company) had any sense, they should just employ you (or contract) to improve the basic usability of the UI directly.